# Make 3 views visible then hide the others based on a condition

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView item on Java that contains several images that will be visible based on some conditions. However, I noticed if most of the conditions are met, many images will be visible and will be out of bound from its parent layout.

Below illustrates how my intention is for this purpose:
[image: What's happening VS Expectation]

The working code is simple for each image in the RecyclerView, e.g.:

```
if (iJobType == 1) {
imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
} else {
imageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE)
}    

if (iJobType == 2) {
imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
} else {
imageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE)
}
```

However, I'm not sure what to do to only show 3 images once 3 conditions are met. Let's say `iJobType` given is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6; that means 6 images will be shown based on such condition, but right now I only need 3 images to be shown.

I hope it's clear enough, feel free to leave comments below to understand this better. Cheers!

Comment: u need to check your image width and your screen width. like.. with every setting of .setVisibility(Visible), increase the occupiedSpace variable and check with total available. something like that

Comment: @Farhan That actually makes great sense! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Maybe visibility isn't the best option. You should try to increment your getItemCount() accordingly to the available space. So the adapter will only call bindViewHolder(VH holder, int position) when there is space

Comment: do you want to show only 3 images even if more than 3 conditions are true?? if yes then what about the other images ,are you going to show them too ??

Answer (score 0):

What i would do in this case is:

Firstly I will create a getter setter boolean isConditionmeet in Object class which is used in adapter class.

e.g. list is used in Adapter class as:

```
 private ArrayList<MyObject> list;
```

and the Object class:

```
public class MyObject
{
  private boolean conditionMeet;

  public boolean isconditionMeet()
  {
    return conditionMeet;
  }

  public void setconditionMeet(boolean conditionMeet)
  {
    this.conditionMeet = conditionMeet;
  }
}
```

Now whenever condition will meet to show Item, i will set setconditionMeet(true) for that item and conditionMeet is false for other Items. Lastly update adapter to get changes in UI.